# Assiging boolean in a ParameterizedThreadStart from a function

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, function, variable-assignment

I have a problem using a ParameterizedThreadStart to asssign a value for a Boolean datatype, it always shows `False` when it returns.

Here's my code:

```
'smth
Frm_ChkHash.Show()
Frm_ChkHash.BringToFront()

Dim BoolH As Boolean
Dim thdC = New Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(Function() BoolH = Frm_ChkHash.MatchHash(Keyl)))
thdC.Start() 
'smth (Wait the thread until exit)
Debug.WriteLine("It is " & BoolH)
'smth
```

The `Debug.WriteLine("It is " & BoolH)` shows `False` in `BoolH`

Tried to make it as Nullable (`Dim BoolH? As Boolean`) it shows nothing on `BoolH`

And here's my `Frm_ChkHash.MatchHash` function code:

```
Public Function MatchHash(ByVal Keyl As String) As Boolean

    Dim nameApp As String = dicLbl.Item(Keyl)
    Debug.WriteLine("Hey! I am checking " & nameApp)

    Thread.Sleep(1500)
    InitHsh()
    Thread.Sleep(2000)

    Dim GetHash As String = KHash.GenerateHash(pathFile, HashCheck.HashType.SHA1) 
    'The KHash.GenerateHash returns a String.
    Thread.Sleep(1500)

    'Find the Actual Hash in the Dictionary through the key.
    Dim ActualHash As String = dicHsh.Item(Keyl)
    Debug.WriteLine("The actual hash is: " & ActualHash)

    Dim StrCmp_Hash As Boolean = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(ActualHash, GetHash)
    Debug.WriteLine("The hash is " & CStr(StrCmp_Hash))

    If StrCmp_Hash = True Then

        Debug.WriteLine("The hash is correct!")
        Debug.WriteLine("It is cool: " & dicHsh.Item(Keyl))
        Debug.WriteLine("And I get : " & GetHash)

        Thread.Sleep(1500)
        Hide()

        Return True

    Else

        Debug.WriteLine("I get" & GetHash & "But it is" & dicHsh.Item(Keyl))

        Thread.Sleep(1500)
        Hide()
        Return False

    End If

    Hide()

End Function
```

My output window shows like this:

```
Hey! I am checking ThisApp       <--- This comes from MatchHash function
The actual hash is: E2133C93F55C7DF4EA44DC0F5455F4A2EE637E8B
The hash is True
The hash is correct!
It is cool: E2133C93F55C7DF4EA44DC0F5455F4A2EE637E8B
And I get : E2133C93F55C7DF4EA44DC0F5455F4A2EE637E8B
The thread 0x8cc has exited with code 0 (0x0).  <--- IDK where this line comes form

It is       <--- The function had returned. ( After `thdC.start()` )
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your delegetate is the '=' operator in your delegate is acting as a compare operator and not the assignment operator.

What it is doing is this:

```
Function() 
    return BoolH = Frm_ChkHash.MatchHash(Keyl)
End If
```

This is why BoolH is null if you make it nullable.

If you want to assign BoolH to value, use 'Sub()' instead of `Function()` or make your delegate a multi line statement.

```
Dim thdC = New Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(Sub() BoolH = Frm_ChkHash.MatchHash(Keyl)))
```

or:

```
Dim thdC = New Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(Function() 
        BoolH = Frm_ChkHash.MatchHash(Keyl)
    End Function)
```

Not that the latter now has no return value.